# How do I understand « à ce que »?

Tags: grammaire

In a sentence like « Les femmes, en particulier, sont à ce qu'il paraît insuffisament protégées contre l'excès du travail » or « Tu vas t'habituer à ce qu'il rentre très tard", why is there an « à ce que »? In what contexts should I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In the first sentence, the idiom "***à ce qu'il paraît***" is used as an *incise*. It roughly means "according to what is said about it/from what they say/according to the grapevine". It is normally separated from the remaining of the sentence by commas, like *en particulier* is. You can remove both *en particulier* and *à ce qui paraît* from the sentence without breaking its grammar.

   This idiom is sometimes written "*à ce **qui** paraît*" which makes less sense grammatically but better match the way we pronounce it. Colloquially, the abbreviated form "[***askip***](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/askip)" can be used.

   When not reporting something heard but your own impression, you can say:

   > *À ce qu'il me paraît*
   > *Autant qu'il me paraît*
   > *À ce qu'il me semble*
   > ...
2. In the second sentence, the preposition "***à***", mandatory with "***s'habituer***", is followed by the subordinate "***il rentre très tard***".

   In such case, the "*locution conjonctive de subordination*" ***à ce que*** is used. There is no way to say "***à que***" in French.

   DeepL translates the second sentence to a different construction:

   > You'll get used to him coming home very late.

   If you want to avoid using the complex "***à ce que***", you can modify the sentence this way:

   > *Qu'il rentre très tard, tu vas t'y habituer.*

   or

   > *Tu vas t'habituer à ses retours très tardifs.*

Answer (score 1):

This is my parse:
1.
Tu vas//t'habituer// à ce qu'//il rentre très tard.

the verb is "s'habituer à quelque chose".

to become accustomed or used to something

[s'habituer à in the Larousse dictionary](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/habituer/38788#:%7E:text=%EE%A0%AC%20%C3%AAtre%20habitu%C3%A9&text=d%C3%A9saccoutumer%20%2D%20se%20d%C3%A9shabituer-,habituer%20v.t.,accomplir%20telle%20ou%20telle%20action.)

*ce* is a deictic pronoun meaning "this" which does not appear in the translation.
And is defined like this in the Larousse:

> **Désigne quelque chose (fonction déictique)** ou représente un groupe
> nominal, un adjectif ou une phrase (fonction anaphorique).

For me, the **ce** is deictic (referential) here. In the French, it refers to coming home late. As it refers to something later in the sentence, it is a cataphor: it refers to something later in the sentence: il rentre très tard.

And here is how I would say it in English: You'll get use to his/him coming home late.

**However,** there is an entirely different way of looking at this as explained in "official French grammar". So, there is another way to look at it.

2)
*à ce que* is defined in the same dictionary, as:

> 4. À ce que, de ce que, **introduisent des complétives de certains verbes transitifs indirects** : Je veillerai à ce que tout aille bien.

The verb veiller is "un verbe transitif indirect". And *s'habituer* is one of them.

Here is a list of those verbs some of which you can use *à ce que* with:

[verbes transitifs indirects](https://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/verbes-transitifs-indirects-a.htm)

It would be impossible to give examples of all the verbs that could be followed by **à ce que**, but here are two examples:

- Ils ont consenti à ce que leur fils part en vacances avec ses amis.
- Je ne m'attendais pas à ce qu'ils me disent tout ça.

3. for the first sentence:

*à ce qu'il parait* and **parait-il** are **set phrases**:

> À ce qu'il paraît, paraît-il, selon les apparences, selon ce qu'on
> dit.

So:
*Les femmes, en particulier, sont //à ce qu'il paraît// insuffisament protégées contre l'excès du travail*

In English: Women in particular are, it would seem, etc.

[Larousse - à ce qu'il parait](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/para%C3%AEtre/57914#:%7E:text=%C3%80%20ce%20qu%27il%20para%C3%AEt,selon%20ce%20qu%27on%20dit.)

[list of some "indirect transitive verbs" in French](https://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/verbes-transitifs-indirects-a.htm)